# Ruby empty String regex

Tags: regex, ruby

Is there any other way than `.match("")`, to specify that my String may as well contain an empty String alongside with some other stuff?
So far my regexp looks like this:

```
s = /(?<beginString>[\sA-Za-z\.]*)(?<marker1>[\*\_]+)(?<word>[\sA-Za-z]+)(?<marker2>[\*\_]+)(?<restString>[\sA-Za-z\*\_\.]*)/ =~ myString
```

now I want to assign beginString an empty String, because the program runs recursively. I want to be able to pass this function a String like `"*this* _is_ ***a*** _string_"` so as you can see, there is plenty possibility that beginString has to be empty in order that it reads the next marker.
In the end I want my program to print this:

```
{"01"=>#<Textemph @content="this ">, "02"=>#<Textemph @content="is">, 
"11"=>#<Textstrongemph @content="a">, "12"=>#<Textemph @content="string">}
```

I think that it might fix my problem if I could just put somthing like `\nil` up there in the [ ].
Please just tell me how to add `.match("")` but in `//`-form.

Thank you for your Help <3

Answer (score -1):

### Match Start-of-String Followed by End-of-String

To match an empty string in Ruby, you could use the `\A` and `\z` atoms to match the beginning of the string immediately followed by the end of the string. For example:

```
"".match /\A\z/
#=> #<MatchData "">
```

Note that this is different from `/^$/`, which doesn't handle newlines as you might expect. Consider:

```
"\n".match /\A\z/
#=> nil

"\n".match /^$/
#=> #<MatchData "">
```

To properly detect an empty string, you need to use start/end of *string* matchers rather than start/end of *line*.